# Environmental variable undefined in React APP

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docker

I am trying to set the URL of the API at runtime. I followed [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-implement-runtime-environment-variables-with-create-react-app-docker-and-nginx-7f9d42a91d70/) tutorial which solves the exact problem I have, but still, the variable is undefined.

I put the file with enviromental variable in script in `index.html` (EDITED)

```
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/env-config.js"></script>
```

Inside of which is (after the image starts through Docker) something like this:

```
window._env_ = {
    API_URL: "my-awesome-url" // filled by bash script defined in ENTRYPOINT
}
```

But when I want to use it in the React app I get something like `cannot read property of undefined API_URL`. When I try to access the `window` object in `console`, I can see, the `_env_` variable is not present in the object. What am I missing?

Comment: place your `env-config.js` inside of `public` folder and change script tag to: `<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/env-config.js"></script>` because you want to use `PUBLIC_URL` variable, not a whole text as variable

Comment: @Wraithy Good catch, it is my mess up here, but I have it right in the real app. Still does not work.

Comment: then you need to put your config into `public` folder... I am using it same way

Comment: I have it in the public folder

Answer (score 1):

The script tag is wrong. It is supposed to be like `<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/env-config.js"></script>`

Check and try again.

Comment: My bad, wasnt copy pasting the code. I have it like so in real app.